# How to delete git branch named "--help"?

Tags: git, escaping, git-branch

I accidentally created a local branch named `--help` and can't figure out how to delete it.  The usual `-D` or `--delete` doesn't work when followed by the `--help`.  It just outputs help text:

```
$ git branch -D --help
usage: git branch [options] [-r | -a] [--merged | --no-merged]
   or: git branch [options]...etc
```

I've tried single `'` and double `"` quotes and get the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git branch -D -- --help`

The first `--` is used to avoid parsing `--help` as a command line option.

Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1520/140838